# PHP and Jquery Ajax Batch Processing Big data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to batch process data using jquery Ajax and PHP. The problem is I am getting timeout issue because of the big data. The request never gets completed and the process dies in the middle.

One way could be to run ajax for certain time and then return the available response in chunk as the request is not completed in a single request. So, to sort out this issue, I tried using setTimeout so that the ajax runs multiple times but only for fixed amount of time. However, I am stuck in the middle. Checked some threads over here but had no help.

```
    function UpdateStatus(){
    $.getJSON(
      "fetch.php",
      {
      },
      function (data, textStatus){
        setTimeout(UpdateStatus, 10000);
      }
    );
  }
  UpdateStatus();
```

Can someone please shade some light on this?

Any help would be more than appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your PHP script gets the timeout. And this can not be avoided by firing the AJAX request multiple time.

You shold try to limit your PHP script time (e.g. by limiting your database request (if you have one) with a limit statement). This result is then used by your javascript code and after that the next chunk of data is requested via AJAX until all data is processed.

Of course you must skip the already handled data in the following requests. That might by done by giving your data some kind of unique id (maybe the primary key of your database records) and sorting by this id. The subsequent request needs to know the last id handled and start from the next data set after this one.

Comment: Thank you @Arno for your reply and suggestions. However, I am not fetching data from database. For example: Fetching links from a website or images. So, how can I possibly pull data on chunk basis as there would be no ids and keys from database.